# Is there a way to print shipping forms from Magento?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

I need to be able to print shipping forms from Magento.  Specifically the USPS Customs and Express Address Labels which I have to use most often.  Is there anything that will allow me to do that?

**NOTE**: I am fully aware of the possibility of using an API to submit everything electronically, however, there are places where I ship to that using it is not possible.

Comment: Hello, sorry, I think I don't understand what kind of solution would satisfy you. Of course there are extensions / you could write a custom one that extends magento's pdf module and enables you to print a well-formatted form for whatever service you use. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer I am looking at any way possible to print those forms.  Generally speaking a specific module if written I would like to use but I wasn't able to find any.  If I have to write one up I will but I need to know if this is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at least for USPS, there are some extensions on [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=usps&pl=0) that you could use.
If you need further customization, I think you will need to code them by yourself. There are two main possibilites:

**1. Move the PDF-stuff to local folder**

Copy the files from `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Pdf` to `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Pdf`. Thus the files in your local directory will be used by Magento, and you can also safely edit them without losing your changes to updates. Magento uses the Zend Framework's PDF class to print the shipping forms. Working with for the first time is a pain, but you'll work it out (and google knows everything).
Advantage: fast to code
Disadvantage: you will edit the only shipping form you have

**2. Write a custom extension**

Don't copy the files, but extend the classes und functions in an own module. This way, you will be able to create multiple shipping form designs; of course, it will take more time/effort than only copying the built-in one.

Ask if you need more advise.
Regards Simon

Comment: Use the second solution, the first is pain in the... when you upgrade you shop in the future. But work for us developers :-)